# how to customize cakephp website for iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, cakephp

I have a website which runs on CakePHP, how do i make my website look better on iphone and ipad?

Is there a plugin i can install and get some advantage or i have to design a custom CSS for iphone and use the same when a particular device type is detected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to create a new mobile layout, and change the layout depending on what type of device the user is accessing the site from.

So inside your `app_controller.php` you have to add the `RequestHandler` component to the `$components` property array, then with the `beforeFilter` function you could use something like this.

```
function beforeFilter() {
    if ($this->RequestHandler->isMobile()) {
        $this->layout = 'mobile_layout';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you help me if we have to use different layout for iPad device?

Answer (score 0):

You need to custom your website to fit on the iphone or ipad Here is a simple tutorial about it

http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/iphone.html

Answer (score 0):

Stoosh is correct.

Rather than creating a new layout in CakePHP you could use CSS media queries to supply sensible styles for mobile.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    /* Iphone styles go here */
}
```

This will allow the browser to select the best styles to use regardless of device type.